# Storing variable using session in jsp

Tags: jsp, session

I have a problem where I am trying to store an ID number from one page throw other page but I have tried I lot of ways all of them end with null the value itself didn't stored if anyone can help with that I will more than thankful
this is the code:
first page

```
idData = rs.getString("ID"); 
first= rs.getString("fName"); 

session.setAttribute("theName",  first);// work probably without a problem
session.setAttribute("Id", idData);// doesn't work or doesn't store anything
```

second page:
is a process for checking and i didn't use them

third page:

```
String Ic = (String)session.getAttribute("Id");
out.print(Ic);
```

I want to use this variable to store one item in the DB using this ID

Comment: Did it occur to you that `rs.getString("ID")` might just have returned `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser does not support session-cookies, enable session-cookies to use sessions.